# How can I get a long listing of text files containing "foo" followed by two digits?

Tags: shell, unix, ls, metacharacters

Using metacharacters, I need to perform a long listing of all files whose name contains the string `foo` followed by two digits, then followed by `.txt`. `foo**.txt` will not work, obviously. I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use Valid Shell Globbing with Character Class

To find your substring anywhere in a filename like `bar-foo12-baz.txt`, you need a wilcard before and after the match. You can also use a character class in your pattern to match a limited range of characters. For example, in Bash:

```
# Explicit character classes.
ls -l *foo[0-9][0-9]*.txt

# POSIX character classes.
ls -l *foo[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]*.txt
```

### See Also

- [Filename Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)
- [Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching)

Answer (score 0):

Something like `ls foo[0-9][0-9]*.txt` of whatever exactly fits your pattern.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit what *[!0-9][0-9] does. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Sorry, copy/paste mistake. Look at the current answer, should be obvious.

Comment: In case it's not: the string `foo`, followed by a character in the range 0 to 9, then another one, then whatever, then `.txt`.